# Sinon stub not getting restored

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, elasticsearch, sinon

I am using elasticsearch client tp get stats from all the nodes
However while unit testing it one of the stubs is not getting restored properly

This is my index.js

```
{ Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
 createAwsElasticsearchConnector = require('aws-elasticsearch-connector'),

 exports.handler = async() => {
     const client = new Client(
                {
                    Connection: createAwsElasticsearchConnector(appropriate creds).Connection, 
                    node: endpointUrl,
                    agent: {
                        keepAlive: ,
                        maxSockets: ,
                        maxFreeSockets: 
                    }
                }
            );

const data = await client.nodes.stats();
//followed by some operations on data
 }
```

This is my index.test.js

```
describe('unit test',()=>{
     const stasresponse = {
                 body: {
                     nodes:{ }
          }
      }
     const nodesApiMock = {
             stats: sinon.stub().resolves(stasresponse),
     };
   let mystub = sino
   before(()=>{
       mystub = sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'nodes').get(() => nodesApiMock);
   });
   after(()=>{
       mystub.restore();
   });

   it('tests',()=>{
        const {handler} = require('./index.js);
        await handler();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(nodesApiMock.stats);
   });
})
```

Everything works fine, but while restoring the mock I get below error

```
 TypeError: Cannot delete property 'nodes' of #<Client>
```

Where am I going wrong here?
I tried reseting the mock, but gives problem in subsequent files while restoring